# How do I get MAAS DHCP to listen on multiple interfaces?

Tags: networking, maas, dhcp

We have MAAS configured and working quite well. Now we want it to offer DHCP leases across multiple interfaces and subnets (for our OpenStack installation), which we have configured through the web interface. The one issue that stopped it working was that the DHCP server was only listening on the primary network interface.

`systemctl cat maas-dhcpd` has `INTERFACES=$(cat /var/lib/maas/dhcpd-interfaces)` and that contains the primary interface name, so we added the others, restarted maas-dhcpd and it started issuing leases as desired. A few seconds later, it went back again to only working on the primary interfaces.

`inotifywait -mr /var/lib/maas/` showed that the file gets overwritten at regular intervals via a temporary file, and after `chattr +i` on the file (a dirty hack IMHO) a syslog entry told me that something like the following is being run:

`for interface in ens3; do echo -n $interface; done | /usr/lib/maas/maas-write-file /var/lib/maas/dhcpd-interfaces 0644`

I couldn't find any further references in the filesystem, so then we thought of the database. A `pg_dump` and `grep` showed only a few references to the network interfaces, none particularly revealing as to how this might be configured.

Can someone suggest how we properly configure MAAS to do this? We could leave in the immutable workaround, but would prefer not to.

Thanks,
Greg.